# Nest.js with Drizzle ORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, drizzle-orm

Are there any more elegant ways to use Drizzle ORM in Nest.js besides the providers? For example like in Prisma with PrismaService, all I found is only with providers like:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import postgres from 'postgres';
import * as schema from './schema';

export const PG_CONNECTION = "PG_CONNECTION"; // ignore that it is not separate file

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PG_CONNECTION,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => {
        const connection = postgres(config.get("DATABASE_URL"));
        return drizzle(connection, { schema });
      },
    },
  ],
  exports: [PG_CONNECTION],
})
export class DrizzleModule {}
```

and then:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PG_CONNECTION } from '../drizzle/drizzle.module';
import { dbType } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js'; // ignore, it doesn't matter yet
import * as schema from '../drizzle/schema';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@Inject(PG_CONNECTION) private drizzle: dbType<typeof schema>) {} // what I'm talking about

  async findAll() {
    return await this.drizzle.query.users.findMany();
  }
}
```

what I'm talking about, we should inject (provider?) every time, import the constant and type from the db client, instead of this:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service'

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async findAll() {
    return await this.prisma.users.findMany();
  }
}
```

I tried to find a solution but it seems this topic is really not popular.. I was expecting such a big Nest.js and Drizzle ORM community to have a good solution to use Drizzle with Nest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own wrapper class around the `PG_CONNECTION` injection token. Something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class DrizzleService {
  constructor(@Inject(PG_CONNECTION) readonly db: dbType<typeof schema>) {}
}
```

And now instead of exporting the `PG_CONNECTION` token from your `DrizzleModule` you export the `DrizzleService`. This would allow you to use the similar `private readonly drizzle: DrizzleService` as you're able to with `prisma` and then access `this.drizzle.db` for your typed database access inside of other providers.